# add authentication danted socks proxy

Tags: proxy, authentication

So I've been using danted socks proxy the past three weeks and it works great however instead of going in and changing which IPs to allow I want to add authentication to it so only those with the right credentials can use my proxy. I tried it using the "username" method but I have no idea how to authenticate on the client side.

My config looks like this:

```
logoutput: stderr
logoutput: /var/log/danted/danted.log

internal: venet0:0 port = 4123
external: venet0:0

method: username #rfc931
clientmethod: none
user.privileged: root
user.notprivileged: nobody
user.libwrap: nobody

client pass {
from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
log: error # connect disconnect
}
pass {
from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
protocol: tcp udp
log: error # connect disconnect
method: username
}
```

and in my error log i get

```
Aug 31 23:22:27 (1346448147) danted[27813]: pass(1): tcp/accept ]: 2.236.77.162.51094 -> 202.231.228.26.4123: client offered no acceptable authenticationmethod
```

so basically my problem is that I don't know how to authenticate on the client and i don't get any popup boxes etc where I can put in my credentials

Answer (score 2):

> I tried it using the "username" method but I have no idea how to
>   authenticate on the client side.
>
> so basically my problem is that I don't know how to authenticate on
>   the client and i don't get any popup boxes etc where I can put in my
>   credentials

According to the [`man sockd.conf`](http://www.inet.no/dante/doc/1.4.x/sockd.conf.5.html):

```
clientmethod
    A  list of acceptable authentication methods for client-rules, 
    in order of preference.
```

The `clientmethod` authentication methods work independently of the configuration of the client. No changes need to be made to the client side.

Either remove the `clientmethod` line or change the `method: username #rfc931` line to `method: username none #rfc931` to see if it works.